# embled if condition in html code and continue with previous div

Tags: php, html, css

```
$custom_column = '<div class="display: table-cell">';
                if(Auth::user()->role_id !==3){
                    '<div class="checkInfo green">
                        <label class="chkcontainer">
                            <input id="internalCheck'. $entery->id . '" onchange="internalOkFunction(this,' . $entery->id . ');return false;" type="checkbox" ' . $kycinternalok . ' >
                            <input id="hiddenId" type="hidden" value="'.$entery->id.'">
                            <span class="checkmark"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>';
                }
```

`<div class="display: table-cell">` not recognize when i set if statement after this. how can i run both `<div class="display: table-cell">` and `if()`?

Comment: Your question is unclear (to me atleast) can you elaborate?

Comment: i put if condition inside a div. but when i run the code that div not find.may be Concatenate  not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data inside the condition block is not added to anything.

You must concatenate to the variable.

```
$custom_column = '<div class="display: table-cell">';
if(Auth::user()->role_id !== 3){
    $custom_column .= '<div class="checkInfo green">
                           <label class="chkcontainer">
                               <input id="internalCheck'. $entery->id . '" onchange="internalOkFunction(this,' . $entery->id . ');return false;" type="checkbox" ' . $kycinternalok . ' >
                               <input id="hiddenId" type="hidden" value="'.$entery->id.'">
                               <span class="checkmark"></span>
                           </label>
                       </div>';
}
```